# How to remove the random stock images from Windows 10's search pane?

Tags: windows-10, spam-prevention, ux

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 21H2 version.

In the last few days, my search pane started to present some random stock photographs (mainly landscapes, I believe) (from Microsoft Bing) upon opening it.

I find this disturbing, because as a primarily keyboard user, as hit the Windows button, then I start to type my search term, for a brief splitsecond, an irrelevant, but impactful blur of color flashes into my vision — that will get promptly replaced as soon as I have typed some characters.

How can I prevent the flare-up of these unwanted images in the search pane?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/image-in-my-search-box-how-to-remove-it/bb80ba33-2f9a-4998-99c9-3db5104f491f):

---

1. right-click the taskbar for a context menu,
2. pick "Search" from the appearing context menu,
3. in the additional flyout menu pane, remove the checkmark from "Show search highlights".

[image]